# How does increasing the freq with which a series steps affect convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If there is a given series $\sum_{i=0}^∞ b_n$ that diverges, how would the infinite sum of $a_{4n}$ behave differently, and what would be a method to compare the two series to test convergence of the latter?

I understand that if $a_{n}$ is decreasing, $a_{(4n)}$ would approach $0$ quicker and therefore be more likely to converge, but I'm not sure how to test for/prove that.

-thanks

Comment: If the sequ now is cauchy, then all subsequences converge and to the same value. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence#:~:text=In%20any%20metric%20space%2C%20a%20Cauchy%20sequence%20which%20has%20a,terms%20of%20the%20original%20sequence